# Has CakePHP anything like Symfony's partials?

Tags: cakephp, symfony1, element, partials

If you want to reuse code in views Symfony has two basic mechanisms: partials and slots. Partials are nice because you can define global partials (you can use them in any module) and module partials (they are only available in a certain module).

However, in CakePHP you only have regular templates and elements, the latter being available in every view, no matter which model/controller you are in.

Does CakePHP have anything like Symfony's partials? It would nice for example to avoid duplicating forms code for a model. You can have two templates (add and edit) that "include" a common form.

I know you can still use elements, but having a "local" elements directory for a module seems to keep things more organized. Can you suggest a workaround to simulate this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not create a view (module_partial.ctp) inside the controller specific view directory. This will keep the code specific to the controller you want it to pertain to. So lets say you have a books controller. You want to add a BooksController specific form to some of your books views.

Create a view in the `views/books/` directory called: `search_partial.ctp`

The `search_partial.ctp` will contain the HTML code you want.

Then, in any view, just call:

```
<?php echo $this->render('search_partial'); ?>
```

This will not prevent other controllers views from loading it, but it keeps the code base readable and segregated as you expect.

ALL of the globals would go into views/elements.

Comment: this is what elements are for, this is more of a hack imo

Comment: It's only a hack if you are breaking MVC rules or you change the core to do something it was not intended to do. This doesn't do either. It allows you flexibility within the rules to make the framework work for the user. I see it as an elegant solution.

Comment: You can add `false` as the second parameter to skip the layout and render the view without being embedded: `<?php $this->render('search_partial', false); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You can put elements in plugins.

You can do something like $this->element('something'); in the layout and have the element in a plugin and/or the main app views folder like such...

```
App/plugins/a_plugin/views/elements/something.ctp //only called when a controller from 'a_plugin' is called.

App/views/elements/something.ctp // called if the current plugin does not have 'something.ctp' in the elements folder
```

For not duplicating views like add/edit look at this https://github.com/infinitas/infinitas/blob/beta/app_controller.php#L389